# Swap key and value mapper hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Is there any mapper class in hadoop that swaps between keys and values? Something similar to the IdentityMapper `Mapper.class`? Just that instead of identity, it swaps between the key and value?

Note: I know that it is simple to implement it, but I am asking if there is already a built-in one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.InverseMapper` which should do what you need. It will swap the key and value.

See: [InverseMapper.java](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/map/InverseMapper.java) and [Javadocs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/map/InverseMapper.html)

There's an implementation for both the `mapreduce` and `mapred` API, the above links are for the `mapreduce` version.